# IF Statement to return specific values in certain order

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, pivot-table, vlookup

I am trying to run an IF Statement to return specific values in a certain order. I have three columns:- `Partner_Number_Col`, `Email_Col`, `Contact_Col`. One Partner Number can hold (match up to) several different Contacts/Emails. There are several different contact options in `Contact_Col`:

1. `Finance_Contact`
2. `Main_Contact`
3. `Blank_Contact` (Specific Email addresses under Email_Col correspond to each of these options)

I wish to look up the partner number (from `Partner_Number_Col`), and then return the Email (from `Email_Col`) that corresponds with (`Contact_Col`), in the order of:

1. `Finance_Contact` (If this does not exist then...
2. `Main_Contact` (If this does not then...
3. `Blank_Contact`

Ie. If `Finance_Contact` is available under `Contact_Col` then I want this to be returned first, `Main_Contact`, then blank...

*Edit to insert image from link in comment:*

[image: SO18339915 question example]

Comment: can you give an example of the data you have and an example of the result so i can provide you a full statement to do the job

Comment: Having a little trouble visualizing it, perhaps you can post some dummy information that will illustrate your problem.

Comment: I can't seem to add an excel file? Is there any way you can see this?

PartnerNo_Col    Email_Col         Contact_Col
P03566453        marshall@pontins.com Finance
P03566453        elena.@hotels.com Main Business Contact
P03566453        taaffe2@pontins.com (Blank)

Comment: Sorry, the view of that looked when I was editing it.

Can you tell me if there is a way to upload an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Here is a link to some sample data. https://sites.google.com/site/excelissues/email-issue
Thanks.

Comment: If you were able to help me out with data I have attached to the link, that would be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

If sorting is not convenient I'd suggest a PivotTable:

[image: SO18339915 example]

and merely (having selected the appropriate Partner_Number in the PT):

```
=IF(A1=B3,B6)
```

(with a rather contrived use of =IF to comply with the stated requirement!)

This will display multiple e-addresses for the same Partner_Number and Contact combination, if present.

*Revised* to incorporate image in line with revised data sample:

[image: SO18339915 second example]

If source data is already in a PT cache there is no need to create a new PT (indeed better not to - if necessary just copy) but this might complicate 'filling in the gaps' because it is a requirement that each row has a `Partner Number`. In cells the gaps can quickly be filled by selecting the column, Home > Editing - Find & Select, Go To Special..., select Blanks (only) and `=`, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort your data, just sort by `Contact_Col` so that all the `Finance_Contact` get on top, `Main_Contact` get just under and the blank ones go to the bottom (if the option is actially blank, you could get a column next to `Contact_Col` where you put 1 for `Finance_Contact`, 2 for `Blank_Contact` and 3 for `Blank_Contact` and sort by this column; ascending)

Then simply do a `VLOOKUP` on this:

```
=VLOOKUP("P03566453", A:B, 2, 0)
```

Since we sorted the data, the `Finance_Contact` gets at the top and if there's none, the next one is `Main_Contact`, and same for `Blank_Contact`.

It will display `#N/A` if the partner number cannot be found in the list.

If you have typed the partner number in cell E5 for example, you can easily do:

```
=VLOOKUP(E5, A:B, 2, 0)
```